# How to set up Vue files formatting in VS Code?

Tags: plugins, vue.js, visual-studio-code

Good day.

I have installed the "Vetur" plugin. And I have nice features for my Vue files (Syntax-highlighting, Snippet, Emmet, Formatting, Auto Completion, Debugging).
But I do not understand how to edit formatting settings!
it transforms my code from this:

```
var map = {
q:"й",w:"ц",e:"у",r:"к",t:"е",y:"н",u:"г",i:"ш",o:"щ",p:"з",a:"ф",s:"ы",d:"в",
```

to that:

```
var map = {
  q: "й",
  w: "ц",
  e: "у",
  r: "к",
  t: "е",
  y: "н",
  u: "г",
  i: "ш",
  o: "щ",
```

How can I edit that behavior?

Comment: Use combination of Ctrl+E, Ctrl+D and Ctrl+F to format the code in your editor.

Answer (score 13):

Easier method is to install vetur `octref.vetur` extension and then add a .vscode>settings.json with following

```
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "prettier",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.css": "prettier",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.postcss": "prettier",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.scss": "prettier",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.less": "prettier",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.stylus": "stylus-supremacy",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "prettier",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.ts": "prettier"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does seems to replace quotes by double quotes when I choose to format Vue documents based on these settings. What if I want to use quotes which seems to be the standard for most things like props or module import paths and such?

Comment: Never mind. We need to add options for prettier like so `"vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
        "prettier": {
            "singleQuote": true
        }`

Comment: Cool, but you can also configure prettier in its own file like below. This is the preferred way!  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLhdI.png

Answer (score -1):

Vetur uses prettier to format js code. You can see how to configure it [here](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/formatting.html). All options for prettier are [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html). But as far as I know, there is no way to adjust the wrapping behaviour of object field definition in prettier.

Comment: The link to configure Vetur is outdated.